# Excel formula to calculate power of

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given the following equation: 2^X - 2 = N

I'd like to solve for X. N is known.

What function could I use in Excel to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that supposed to be 2^(X-2)= N or (2^X) - 2 = N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=(log(A1+2)/log(2))` where A1 is the source cell.

Answer (score 3):

```
X = log(N+2)/log(2)
```

`log` is an Excel function, the rest is more about solving an equation.

Answer (score 1):

Put X in a cell and use the goal seek function, e.g.:

- in <kbd>A1</kbd>, enter a value of X, e.g. 1
- in <kbd>A2</kbd>, enter the formula `=2^A1-2`
- Data Menu \ What If analysis \ Goal Seek
- Set cell <kbd>A2</kbd> to value <kbd>N</kbd> by changing cell <kbd>A1</kbd>